# pack language .ini or .php

Tags: php, internationalization, ini

There is a benchmark to measure the performance between `parse_ini_file` and include common?

I need to work with a language pack and I am in doubt whether I use `.ini` or `.php`

Could someone tell me what the positives and negatives of each way?

Thank you

Comment: I think not quite understand, sorry: (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how edits those files; are you considering .ini format to help translators? If so, that's an important design decision.

If who edits the files is not important, the next up is performance. In this case, `parse_ini_file` will always be slower; you can't beat `include()`, because it can be highly optimized (using opcode caches, think `APC`).

Even if the performance were the same, the .ini is limited in terms of expressiveness; a .php data structure can describe more, can use objects, etc.

Comment: if parse_ini_file is slower, I will use include. Thanks for the help

Comment: As mentioned by Zheng Kai, if this is specifically for localisation files, you might want to consider `gettext`. It uses binary files and is written in C, so it should outperform whatever you write in PHP :)

Comment: Already tried working with Gettext, but he needs installation. I do not know the server configuration, so Gettext will be the final step. Yet thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), the common way of Internationalization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look here: [PHP ini vs array performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606741/php-ini-vs-array-performance/16606811?noredirect=1#comment23873448_16606811)

i've done a test between an php file that contains an array and an ini file with 10.000 values each.

array (php) wins ;)

and array will win every time, because the server is basically optimized for reading php files (see also Jacks answer) and can load the array faster. reading an ini file means also to parse the ini into an array.

br